# Android Studio 2.3.1 -> 2.3.3 Access Denied

Tags: android, android-studio

After trying to update from A.S. 2.3.1 to 2.3.3 I received the following error. How can I continue the update? From other Stack Overflow answers, the only solution seems to be deleting A.S. and starting over, I was hoping there would be an easier way.

**Before I update**
[image]

(the writing in red: `Studio does not have write access to /private/var/folders/8c/3ffqd8814c37fw3197jq6k0r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/FA3D0850-457F-489F-BA09-221516148C30/d/Android Studio.app/Contents. Please run it by a privileged user to update.`)

**Error After Hitting Update**
[image: Error after hitting update]

**After I hit Cancel**
[image: After I hit Cancel]

Comment: Do you add Android Studio file to Application folder?

Comment: Yes AS is in my Application folder

Comment: You can try with sudo command: `sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`. I have problems like you, maybe I use this way to update. I do some ways like restart macbook, run sudo.

Comment: @RoShanShan that doesn't work. I am not totally sure what it did to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to directory ownership and permission. You can run the update with the user privilege that you use when installing Android Studio or use root privilege.

Or you can grant the write permission to your current username. Something like this (you need to run this as root):

```
chown -R yourusername /private/var/folders/
```

Or you can grant the write permission temporarily by using:

```
chmod +w /private/var/folders/
```

Then after you update the Android Studio, remove the permission:

```
chmod -w /private/var/folders/
```

Or you can use **a+w** and **a-w** for giving and removing permission for all.

Comment: Could you clarify the command? Would running in root mean using sudo?

Comment: chown is change owner, the first line is changing the owner of the directory to yourusername. chmod is change the access permission of the directory, here +w means adding write access to the directory. Yes, you can use sudo in front of the line. So it will be `sudo chown -R yourusername /private/var/folders/`

Comment: Ok awesome, and how temporary is +w?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realize it. After you granting the +w and updating the AS, you need to remove the access again by using -x.

Comment: Ok great so first run `sudo chown -R yourusername /private/var/folders/` then run update then run `sudo chown -x yourusername /private/var/folders/`

Comment: no, you run either `sudo chown -R` or `sudo chown +x`. Only use `sudo chown -x` if you use `sudo chown +x`

Comment: OK so after running `sudo chmod +w /private/var/folders/ ` I am still receiving this error when I try to update. `Studio does not have write access to /private/var/folders/8c/3ffqd8814c37fw3197jq6k0r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/5AF9FF72-940D-446F-ABAD-4DC37D689158/d/Android Studio.app/Contents. Please run it by a privileged user to update.`

Comment: try use `a+w` instead of `+w`

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -R a+w /private/var/folder` or `sudo chmod 777 -R  /private/var/folder`

Comment: I wanted to clarify something that may be an issue. My folder structure is /Users/myname/Applications, but Android Studio is not in that applications folder (not much is), rather AS is in /Applications. On root I believe

Comment: I get the following `chmod: /private/var/folder: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's is a typo. Should be `/private/var/folders`

Comment: I got a long string of this `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000010m000085/T: Operation not permitted`